# Grails not automatically adding jar to classpath

Tags: grails, dependencies, libraries

Grails is able to configure dependencies when you specify them in the BuildConfig.groovy file.  Usually when you add it there and call `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` it will resolve the dependency, and download to .grails/ivy-cache/..... (in my case).  However, one time, after downloading the jar files, it failed to automatically add the jar to the classpath. Does anybody have any idea on how this will happen?  It has worked for me before on many other Maven repository dependencies.  The specific dependency I failed to add to my Grails project classpath is http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4.7

I can just manually add the lib to the classpath, but I'd rather have dependencies resolved automatically with the BuildConfig.groovy file.  I also can't manually add jars into the "Grails Dependencies" library in the classpath; they can only be outside that library.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What's the error that's happening? Adding the BuildConfig.groovy source will help too.

Comment: The error is that the dependency is not added to the classpath, even though it is downloaded to .grails/ivy-cache.

`dependencies {
         build 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
    }`

Comment: "not added to the classpath" - how you confirmed that? Are you using grails run-app?

Comment: Yes, I've used `grails clean`, `grails compile --refresh-dependencies`, and then `grails run-app`

Comment: Ok, so you have a stacktrace of the error, right? Can you post it?

Comment: `build` dependencies is used by build system. May be you should change it to `compile`?